# Allow user to create live folder?

Tags: android

I have been looking at live folders and I am wondering if I can make it in an app where the user can create a live folder via the app. I have noticed that it is possible to create a live folder via coding as shown [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/live-folders.html). The whole point of my app is to allow to user to create a completely editable folder on the homescreen (icon, name, and background) from the app. Am I going about this the correct way? I understand that "You cannot add live folders, app widgets, etc. to the user's home screen. Users need to request them via a long-click on the home screen or other mechanism that the home screen provides." So is there anyway that I CAN do this? I know there must be a way somehow. 
Thanks!

Added:
I also found someone say this on the internet while looking around on how to do this:
You need to have the `permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

And the code is similar to Java. You can read up or search on how to 
do that in Java, and the same code should work as well on Android.

```
String tempFilePath = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                            + File.separator + "your_folder_name"; 
File file = new File(tempFilePath); 
file.mkdir();
```

Is this what I would need to do? Can someone please give me any helpful links or explain a little on what is being done here?

Answer (score 0):

Snippet you have posted is Directory in Java which is created on Sdcard.
Blog you have refered to is showing how you can create a custom Folder Widget in android.
These two are completely different concepts.
Former one is concept in java and later on is concept of Android OS.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Ignoring the snippet though I guess, could I create the app where the user can create a custom Folder Widget in android?